# Roots of a polynomial with one parameter

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $P$ be the polynomial defined by $P (Z) = Z^{4}-aZ^{2} +1$
>
> Calculate $P\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}\right)$ and deduce the number of real roots of $P$ as the case $a = 2$, $a >2$ or $a <2$.

My attempt:

- **First Method**

$P\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}\right)=\dfrac{a^{2}}{4}-a\dfrac{|a|}{2}+1$

- *Case $a=2$*

$\Longrightarrow P\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}\right)=0 $ then the polynomial $P$ has solution $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}=1$

as $1$ is root of $P$ then by Euclidean division the polynomial has  the following factors:
$$P(Z)=(Z-1).(Z^{3}+2^{2}-2+1)$$

note that $(Z^{3}+2^{2}-2+1)$ has trivial roots $1$ and $-1$ then by Euclidean division

\begin{align}
P(Z)&=(Z-1)^{2}.(Z^{2}+2Z+1)\\
&=(Z-1)^{2}.(Z+1)^{2}
\end{align}

Then $P$ has multiple roots $-1$ and $1$ .

- *Case $a>2$*

\begin{align}
P\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}\right)&=\dfrac{a^{2}}{4}-a\dfrac{|a|}{2}+1\\
&=1-\dfrac{a^{2}}{4}
\end{align}

let $Y=Z^{2}$ then $P(Z)=Q(Y)=Y^{2}-aY+1$

the discriminant of $Q$ is $\Delta=a^{2}-4$
as $a>2 \Longrightarrow  \Delta >0$ then $Q$  has two real roots $Y=\left( \dfrac{a \pm \sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{2}\right)$ thus $P$  has two real roots $Z^{2}=\left( \dfrac{a \pm \sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{2}\right) \Longrightarrow  $

- *Case $a<2$*

let $Y=Z^{2}$ then $P(Z)=Q(Y)=Y^{2}-aY+1$ as $a<2$ then $\Delta<0$  has no real roots

- **Second Method**

Using Intermediate value theorem

- *Case $a>2$*

$P'(Z)=4Z^{3}-2.aZ$ then if $P'(Z)=0 \Longrightarrow  Z=0  \text{ or }  Z=\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}$

- on $[0, \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}]$

  since $P$ is  monotone and continuous on $[0, \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}]$ then by Intermediate value theorem Then there exists $Z$ between $0$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}$ such that $P(Z)=c$.

on $[\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}},+\infty]$

since $P$ is  monotone and continuous on $[0, \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}]$ then by Intermediate value theorem Then there exists $Z$ between $+\infty$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{2}}$ such that $P(Z)=c$.

*Case $a<2$*

there is solution just in case of $0<a<2$ and its the same as above

- My reasoning, is it correct ?
- Is there another simple ways to solve that question ?
- **I add the new follwing method:**

> $P(Z)=Z^{4}-aZ^{2}+1=(Z^{2}-\dfrac{a}{2})^2-\dfrac{a^{2}-4}{4}$
>
> immediately gives the results :

- for case a=2

$ P(Z)=(Z-1)^{2}(Z+1)^{2}$ then p has two multiple solution on $\mathbb{R}$

- For Case $|a|<2$

then $P(Z)$ is a sum of two squares, one of which is not zero so $P(z) > 0$ then P has non roots on $\mathbb{R}$

- For Case $|a|>2$

the canonical form of $P(z)$ is a difference of squares so we can factor as :

$$P(Z)=(z-\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{2})(z-\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{2})$$

then $P$ has two solution on $\mathbb{R}$

- For Case $a=-2$

we've  $P(Z)=(Z^{2}+1)^{2}\geq 1$ then p has no solution on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is essentially the way to go. You could have obtained the factorization in the case $a=2$ as follows :

Since 
$$
P(z) = z^4 - 2z^2 + 1 = (z^2)^2 - 2(z^2) + 1 = q(z^2)
$$
where $q(z) = z^2 - 2z + 1 = (z-1)^2$ (if you don't see this, the rational root theorem tells you the only possible roots of $q$ are $\pm 1$, so you can check if they are and then use the Euclidean algorithm or write $z = z-1+1$, substitute and expand). Therefore $p(z) = (z^2-1)^2 = (z-1)^2 (z+1)^2$.

This is better in some sense because you don't have to factor a quartic by hand.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks but this is just only for one case $a=2$ and which one is correct or they are both

Comment: @Educ : I said your way was fine, I just added that in the case $a=2$ you factored a quartic and you didn't have to!

Comment: I think there is another way more stylish to do this

Comment: @Educ : If you want to explain yourself, go ahead! I'm listening.

Comment: see my update please and thanks for ur time

Comment: @Educ : Watch out, the real solutions are only for $a \ge 2$. But completing the square is of course a general way to go too.